# Propositional logic with implicit equations

Tags: logic, implicit-function

I've been playing around with the idea of performing logic with implicit equations. For example, given the implicit equations
$$\begin{matrix} A:\; \; F(x,y,z,\dots) = F = 0 \\ B:\; \; G(x,y,z,\dots) = G = 0 \end{matrix}$$
we can:

AND: $A \wedge B \equiv {F}^2 + {G}^2 = 0$

OR: $A \vee B \equiv FG = 0$

I was trying to think of a nice way to do NOT and came up with

NOT: $¬A \equiv \lim\frac{\mathcal{O}\left(F_1(x)\right)}{F_1(x)}$

but I feel like there is a smarter way to do it. Any ideas?